# Stripe.net login link

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe.net

Hello I'm having trouble with stripe.net login link use with my connected Express accounts. The below code never throws an error but stops the view from ever loading, it just sits their acting like its trying to load. The account id matches a connected test account id my correct keys are in place. Im using VS 2017 and Stripe.net 11.10.0 (updated today hoping to resolve issue).

```
var loginLinkService = new StripeLoginLinkService();
StripeLoginLink loginLink = loginLinkService.Create(account.Id);
ViewBag.link = loginLink.Url;
```

Comment: From ob-stripe "There might be an issue with your test account. In any case, I don't think it's an issue with the stripe-dotnet client library -- if the request does not return anything, it's likely an issue on the API's end. Can you reach out to support at https://support.stripe.com/email to ask about this issue? Make sure to include the ID of your test Express account, and if you can, timestamps for the login link creation requests you sent. We will be able to dig into your account's logs and help you figure out what's happening exactly." https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/1081

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  I have my code in a try{} block, but the catch{} after never gets hit.  It's like the thread just dies and my request is left pending.  very odd.

Comment: I emailed stripe support ( https://support.stripe.com/email ) this Sunday with example issue, they are still investigating. Dexter with support@stripe.com told me to use `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/xxxyyyzzz/login_links -X POST -u sk_test_xxxyyyyzzzz:` in the meantime.